# Make a PHP file accesable only via my C# application?

Tags: c#, php, sql, security, authentication

I got a little questions for you all! Currently I have a login form on my C# application and you need to enter the right user and pass to open another form that is the real program. To do this I got this line of codes:

```
            string response = SendRequest("http://mysite/login.php?name=" + userName);
            string[] back = response.Split('_');
            back[0] = back[0].Replace(" ", "");
            back[0] = back[0].ToUpper();
```

and I got this method:

```
    private string SendRequest(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                return client.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error while receiving data from the server.","Something broke.. :(", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I also have a method that checks if the entered password = the stored passwod in the database

```
$dbConnection = new mysqli("SERVER", "LOGIN", "PASS", "DBNAME");
$email = $_GET['name'];
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT password, salt FROM TABLE WHERE email = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($pass, $salt);
$stmt->fetch();
echo "$pass" . "_" .  "$salt";
```

This works fine and I can login when I enter the right password and I can't when I enter the wrong password.

My problem though is if I enter : http://mysite/login.php?name=[username]
where **[username]** is any username it returns the hashed and salted password. Since it's hashed and salted this is not a big issue but later when I will do inserts this will become a bigger problem since then someone could enter information into the tables with this method. So my question is: **Is there anyway to make the PHP file only allow to return the values if the connections come from my C# application?**

Comment: Check the PHP `$_SERVER` manual. Maybe you can use something called http referrer or something like that.

Comment: put your php file out of your public folder. It needs not be visible from the internet to execute successfully. If the c# script and the php script reside on the same computer, that is.

Comment: Sadly they are not on the same computer. Every user on my site will have this application so that wont be an option then I guess? :l

Comment: however, you seem to be using prepared statements and parameterized queries, so you should not really worry about sql injection, should you?

Comment: Im not really worried about sql injection, just that if someone got the URL to that page and just wrote...?name=adminname  he would get the hashed password for the admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really interested in managing this in a manner such as that, you should do one of the following:

**Implement an OAUTH Configuration**

You should implement a form of **OAUTH** in your PHP app, and generate the right proper tokens for your C# app. You would then use a full **OAUTH** dialogue to send/retrieve the data from the PHP server. This would eliminate the possibility for random queries to the page to return proper results. You should also implement **HTTPS** with this. PHP **OAUTH** implementation basics: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-php-oauth-server/

Advantages: **Security**. This method provides a greater deal of security than the others, **without** sacrificing the robustness of the project in general. You would also be able to remove the entire **GET**/**POST** request by using tokens for each client, instead of a **GET** against username. **Extensibility**. This method can be easily extended to provide features for further apps/programmes.

Disadvantages: **Complexity**. This method is much more complex and has much more overhead than the others.

**Modify the Request to be a POST with Secret**

Another option is to change the C# programme to send a **POST** request to the PHP page, and send some secret value with it as well. This is not recommended, as anyone who knows the secret value could send it from a malicious page. This is equivalent to implementing basic **XSS** attack prevention. You should also use **HTTPS** for this as well.

Advantages: **Simplicity**. This method is the quickest/easiest to implement without removing any current features.

Disadvantages: **Insecurity**. This method does not provide any security benefits, apart from *security through obscurity*.

**Alter Database Visibility**

Since you are using **MySQL** on the PHP page to return the value, you should modify the C# programme to connect directly to the **MySQL** database and collect the value. This has the advantage of eliminating the possibility of someone with malicious intent querying the PHP page without your permission. Various MySQL connectors: https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Advantages: **Moderate Security**. This method does remove the possibility of PHP exploits, and also assists in keeping the database secret.

Disadvantages: **Moderate Insecurity**. This method requires embedding the connection string (with username and password) into the application when distributed. Certain measures could be taken to assist in eliminating some of the issues with this, but in general this method is an average method. **Code Rewrites**. This method requires an entire rewrite of the programming infrastructure.

**Custom User Agent**

Edit: Forgot to mention, another simple/easy workaround that is extremely insecure.

You could utilize a custom **User Agent** (similarly to the **secret** in the **POST** method.) This would allow your PHP page to determine that the request *likely* came from your application. You should, again, use **HTTPS** for this method as well. This method would not require much code change, and could be combined with **HTTP_REFERER** to assist in securing the origin as well.

Advantages: **Simplicity**. This is, by far, the easiest method to implement.

Disadvantages: **Insecurity**. Much like the **POST with Secret** method, this is *extremely* insecure. Anyone who knows how your **User Agent** is formed could quite simply and readily exploit it. Using **HTTPS** would likely help mitigate this risk, but it would never go away.

*Examples*:

C#: `client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "my-super-insecure-user-agent");`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

PHP: `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] === "my-super-insecure-user-agent") {/*Process request*/}`
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

**Tl;dr**

Ultimately, the choice is yours. Given the situation, I would recommend using the following advisories:

1. If development time is not an issue, utilize the **OAUTH** model. This is the most expandable and secure method.
2. If you can eliminate the PHP in general, use the **Database Visibility** model. This has the advantage of removing the inherit security risks associated with having a publicly-visible PHP page. You could also use this model, with more efficiency and speed, if the database is always local to the users network. This also means that outsiders could not access your information, if properly fire-walled.
3. If you need a quick-and-dirty solution, use the **POST** model. This would be the fastest and simplest to implement, but the ***least secure***.

Comment: Yeah I was using a direcet connection to the database on my C# program before, the problem was that anyone could decompile it and get the connectionstring..

Comment: That is true, however even with a solution similar to the **OAUTH** solution I provided ,you must embed some sort of token/information into the client. The advantage of the **OAUTH** solution is that you could more appropriately distribute permissions: give each client a key/secret and use it instead of the **GET/POST** request.

Comment: Also, added another option you could use, that would be simple/easy to implement: **Custom User Agent**.

Comment: can you make any example on how I can use that?

Comment: Added, though I recommend you not use it.

Comment: Hmm I would like to use the OATH but im not sure how to implement it.. :/

Comment: Check the link at the end of the first paragraph under that heading, it has examples on setting it up. If you like the answer, mark it solved.